# Coffeescript class scope issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am probably doing something obviously wrong but I can't seem to call an instance method from the constructor of a coffeescript class.

It could also be a more general error I'm making so I'll show you the context of where it's happening.

I have two classes: BaseView and ChildView. ChildView extends BaseView. BaseView has a recursive method that populates one of its attributes with a tree of child instances. Like so:

BaseView:

```
class BaseView
  constructor: (@xml) ->
    console.log(@) #this logs X
    @.children = @.populateChildren()

  populateChildren: () ->
    out = []
    _.each(@.xml, (node) ->
      out.push(new require("./child")(node))
    )
    return out
```

ChildView:

```
BaseView = require('./base')
class ChildView extends BaseView
    constructor: (@xml) -> super
```

I initialize a new ChildView by:

```
ChildView = require('./child')
childView = new ChildView(someXML)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'populateChildren'
```

And you can see why from the X console.log in BaseView

```
    { ArrayBuffer: [Function: ArrayBuffer],
      Int8Array: { [Function: Int8Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 1 },
      Uint8Array: { [Function: Uint8Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 1 },
      Uint8ClampedArray: { [Function: Uint8ClampedArray] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 1 },
      Int16Array: { [Function: Int16Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 2 },
      Uint16Array: { [Function: Uint16Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 2 },
      Int32Array: { [Function: Int32Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
      Uint32Array: { [Function: Uint32Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
      Float32Array: { [Function: Float32Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 4 },
      Float64Array: { [Function: Float64Array] BYTES_PER_ELEMENT: 8 },
      DataView: [Function: DataView],
      global: [Circular],
      process: ...
      GLOBAL: [Circular],
      root: [Circular],
      Buffer: 
       { [Function: Buffer]
         isEncoding: [Function],
         poolSize: 8192,
         isBuffer: [Function: isBuffer],
         byteLength: [Function],
         concat: [Function],
         _charsWritten: 669 },
      setTimeout: [Function],
      setInterval: [Function],
      clearTimeout: [Function],
      clearInterval: [Function],
      setImmediate: [Function],
      clearImmediate: [Function],
      console: [Getter],
      before: [Function],
      after: [Function],
      beforeEach: [Function],
      afterEach: [Function],
      context: { [Function] skip: [Function], only: [Function] },
      describe: { [Function] skip: [Function], only: [Function] },
      xcontext: [Function],
      xdescribe: [Function],
      specify: { [Function] only: [Function], skip: [Function] },
      it: { [Function] only: [Function], skip: [Function] },
      xspecify: [Function],
      xit: [Function],
      xml: [ 'row', [ 'col', [Object], [Object] ] ],
      data: 
       { 'mentions-per-day': 
          { legend: [Object],
            tooltip: [Object],
            yAxis: [Object],
            xAxis: [Object],
            subtitle: [Object],
            title: [Object] },
         data: { 'number-of-mentions': '3', 'mentions-per-day': [Object] } },
      options: {} }
```

You can see that something is messed up with the scope somehow but I can't figure out what. I quess maybe it's got something to do with the circular dependency... Please help me out here anybody! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's just a more-or-less obvious typo:

```
@.children = @.populateCildren()
#                      ^
```

should be

```
@.children = @.populateChildren()
```

but notice that omitting the dot is more idiomatic:

```
@children = @populateChildren()
```

Comment: sorry for the super delayed reply - but no that wasnt the cause even though you were right. I mistyped it when I was posting the question. Still haven't been able to resolve the issue but have moved on.
It works if you put all the classes in the same file. If theyre in different files then it becomes an issue